# Test Context value null when called in inherited class

Tags: c#, selenium, testcontext

I have one test method in which i have called one function and in that function it further calls the evaluate function as which is mentioned below.

```
protected bool Evaluate(bool condition, string message)
    {
        if (!condition)
        {
            Driver.Browser.GetScreenShot(@SKPConfigSettings.Logging.ScreenShotPath, TestContext.TestName, Core.Drivers.Enums.ScreenshotFormat.Png, true);
            Logger.LogError(message);
            Logger.LogError(Constants.Messages.TCFail);
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;

    }
```

**Problem** is `TestContext.TestName` is always `null` , it does not gets the method name. It gets the method name in the test method but not in this way. Can anyone provide the solution?

Comment: Looks  like its a public static variable that has never been initialized.  It is better to use instances of classes than make them static to prevent un-initialized variables.

Comment: No i havent declared it as static, it is declared in this manner :              public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }

Comment: You will need to provide the rest of the code. Include the entirety of the file as well as the testcontent class.

Comment: That is what happens when you use the same name for the class and the property.  Try making the property name start with a lower case 't'.

Comment: @jdweng - Doesnt work even with the lower case.

Comment: Are you getting compiler errors or runtine errors?

Comment: Run Time -- System.nullreference